# Get the remote branches within groovy script in jenkins

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, scripting, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to add a parameter to jenkins using Active choice parameter in order to populate the list of branches. I am trying to use the below codes for groovy script to capture the remote branches.

```
def gettags = ("git ls-remote -t -h https://credentials@github.com/org/repo.git").execute()
return gettags.text.readLines().collect { 
  it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
```

I also tried using ssh

```
def gettags = ("git ls-remote -t -h git@github.com:org/repo.git").execute()
return gettags.text.readLines().collect { 
  it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
```

But I am unable to fetch the remote branches. I am assuming I am not passing the credentials proeprly. I am using the credentials stored in my jenkins.

Can any one guide me on this.

Comment: Have you tried just using the [List Git Branches Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/list-git-branches-parameter/) plugin ?

Comment: @Ian W Yes..Its working with that..But i want to write a custom script for filtering the branches getting populated based on the increasing or decreasing order of commits.